# parsing an image in order to get the information out of it 

Tags: mysql, perl, image, ocr

Several days i mused about the three-folded job of

a. getting 
b. parsing 
c. storing a number of pages.

Two days ago i  thought that getting the pages would be the major-task. No this isnt the case - i guess that the parser-job would be a heroic task. Each of the pages  that are intended to be parsed is a png-image.

So the question is - after getting all them. How to parse them!? This seems to be the issue. Guess that there are some perl-modules out there - that can help in doing this...

Well - i think that this job only can be done with some OCR embedded! Question: is there a perl-module that can be use here to support this task:

BTW: see the result-pages.

[image: see an image]

BTW;: and as i thought i can find all 790 resultpages within a certain range between 
Id= 0 and Id= 100000 i thought, that i can go the way with a loop:

http://www.foundationfinder.ch/ShowDetails.php?Id=11233&InterfaceLanguage=&Type=Html 
http://www.foundationfinder.ch/ShowDetails.php?Id=927&InterfaceLanguage=1&Type=Html 
http://www.foundationfinder.ch/ShowDetails.php?Id=949&InterfaceLanguage=1&Type=Html 
http://www.foundationfinder.ch/ShowDetails.php?Id=20011&InterfaceLanguage=1&Type=Html 
http://www.foundationfinder.ch/ShowDetails.php?Id=10579&InterfaceLanguage=1&Type=Html

i thought i can go the Perl-Way but i am not very very sure: 
I was trying to use LWP::UserAgent on the same URLs [see below] 
with different query arguments, and i am wondering if LWP::UserAgent provides a 
way for us to loop through the query arguments? I am not sure that LWP::UserAgent has a method for us to do that. Well - i sometimes heard that it is easier to use Mechanize. But is it really easier!?

But - to be frank; The **first task " GETTING all the pages** is not very difficult - if we compare this task with **the parsing**... How **can this be done**!?

Any ideas - suggestions -

look forward to hear from you...

zero

Comment: Does this need to be Perl? You may be better off with an OCR suite that is specialized on layout recognition.

Comment: Hello dear Mu is too short: Thx for correcting  the Tags. Well great. BTW: i love your site: The cakes are so great. And your philosphy is overwhelming! hello Pekka, Well - many many thanks for he qukck reply. Well It does not have to be Perl. But i think - the Part to get the stuff can be done with Perl. Afterwards i have to run some kind of OCR.- What do you think!? Do you have some OCR in mind!? Look forward to hear from you!!

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a specific product in mind, but I'm sure there is one. But on a related note, who had the idea of putting this kind of data into *images*? I have never seen anything like this before. Are you authorized to scrape the data? If you are, shouldn't there be a way to get hold of the actual text data?

Comment: hello dear Pekka - i do not have an answer for the question of putting the data in to images. Nasty guys over there. But with the permissions - i have no issue. The foundationfinder is free to use. All i am doing is to mechanize the "reading" - somewhat and somekind of (high) speed-reading. I could read page by page - this would be very  very slow. If i use Perl to support the fetch-(get)process i can speed up some tasks. So i think there are no legal issues.... it s all about doing things easier with Perl...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `Image::OCR::Tesseract`

I've had good experience with **Tesseract** in the past using C++.

See [this](http://search.cpan.org/~leocharre/Image-OCR-Tesseract-1.24/lib/Image/OCR/Tesseract.pod) for further info.

Comment: good day soulSurfer 2010 many  thanks i will try this out! Mille grazie!